# How to store multiple emails in Ruby hash in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I built my own comments in my rails app without threading and I want to be able to send reply all notifications for new comments on a project. Would it be best to just store emails into a ruby hash in MySQL and then read from it when necessary? I'm trying to figure out how to insert emails into a hash with keys I don't have to define, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some column with `string` type in some mysql table.

Use `json` gem. If you don't have `json` gem install it by `gem install json`.

```
require 'json'
reply_emails_list = ["a@gmail.com", "b@gamil.com"]
obj.column_name = {:emails => reply_emails_list}.to_json  #storing ruby hash as string in mysql
```

To get ruby hash back use `JSON.parse(obj)'

```
emails_list = JSON.parse(obj.column_name)  #ruby hash
```

or

In rails way. In model you can do like this:

```
YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :column_name, Array  #If don't want hash
  serialize :column_name     #you can store key value pair as I shown above
end
```

Using second will avoid converting from `hash` to `json` and vice versa

Comment: Does the column type need to be string, or can it be text?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, there is an array extension you can use to get actual array storage.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for MySQL.

The best thing for data like e-mails would be to serialize your list of emails as a String field and provide a synthetic attribute that provides an array accessor (if needed).  You can then put callbacks on your comment to update the email list when Comments are added to this Project.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  # db String field email_list
  attr_accessor :emails

  def emails
    email_list.split(',')
  end

  def emails=(email_ary)
    self.email_list = email_ary.join(',')
  end
end
```

This can be a good alternative to using a JSON blob, as it allows easier text searching and handling of a comma separated list.  I don't know if split() or JSON.parse provide an advantage in terms of serialization performance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`ActiveRecord::Base`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays%2C+hashes%2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns) you can `serialize` a column:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :emails
end

User.create(:emails => %w( email1@a.com email2@b.com email3@c.com )
```